# Difficulty positioning images using CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, image

I am experiencing difficulty positioning (or more accurately, combining) various graphical images to form *one* complete image using CSS.  The reason I am doing it this way is so that (eventually), when I have them correctly placed in the header of the web site I am building, I would be able to use easing CSS animation to bring them together.

The **bigger picture** consists of the following graphic images:

[image: Solid Line]

[image: Curve UP]
[image: Curve DOWN]

[image: Greek Key]
[image: Greek Coin]

The way I want it to look is like this:

[image: Expected Header Image]

With the CSS that I have below, it is looking something like this:

[image: Actual Header Image]

Here is the CSS and HTML code:

```css
.clip_frame
/* used to clip the contents as in the case of an image frame */

{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.middleContent {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.middleContent > img {
  display: inline-block;
}
.centervertical {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.header-left {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.header-left-top {
  vertical-align: top;
  position: absolute;
}
.header-left-bottom {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: absolute;
}
.header-right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.header-right-top {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.header-right-bottom {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-bottom: 20;
  position: absolute;
}
.center-top {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.center-top > img {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.center-bottom {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.center-bottom > img {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<?php /* Wrapper Name: Header */ ?>. . .
<div class="row">
  <div class="middleContent">
    <div class="clip_frame centervertical">
      <div class="clip_frame header-left">
        <span class="clip_frame header-left-top">
                        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuJmJ.gif" alt="" width="500" height="6px"/>
                    </span>

        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KDly.gif" alt="" width="500" height="80" />

        <span class="clip_frame header-left-bottom">
                        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuJmJ.gif" alt="" width="500" height="6px"/>
                    </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clip_frame centervertical">
      <span class="clip_frame center-top">
                    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kujPV.gif" alt="" width="238" height="70"/>
                </span>

      <span class="clip_frame" data-motopress-type="static" data-motopress-static-file="static/static-logo.php">
                    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOmBd.gif">
                </span>

      <span class="clip_frame center-bottom">
                    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpZ1l.gif" alt="" width="238" height="70"/>
                </span>
    </div>

    <div class="clip_frame centervertical">
      <div class="clip_frame header-right">
        <span class="clip_frame header-right-top">
                        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuJmJ.gif" alt="" width="500" height="6px"/>
                    </span>

        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KDly.gif" alt="" width="500" height="80" />

        <span class="clip_frame header-right-bottom">
                        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuJmJ.gif" alt="" width="500" height="6px"/>
                    </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have embedded into a PHP header wrapper:

Note that I am using the Cherry Framework of WordPress, hence the definition of the 'row' class selector is not defined by the theme that I am developing.  It's purpose, however, is to vertically align text/images into rows of a table, which apparently the Cherry Framework uses to structure the header of each page.  Nevertheless, I do not believe that this should interfere with what I am trying to achieve.  Correct me if I am wrong....  Any advice and/or feedback, including suggestions about using easing css animation, would be appreciated.

N.B. The actual logo that I am using is not the one that I have provided here.  It is in fact a greyscale 182x182 gif image.

Comment: i think it can be fixed with the use of `top`, `bottom`, `right`, `left` values .

Comment: @Amitsingh - Thanks Amit, I have already tried that - makes no difference, unless I am not doing it correctly....

Comment: can you set a fiddle for this ??

Comment: @ShowStopper - If you are referring to jsFiddle, I'll see what I can do....

Comment: @Bill if you provide fiddle than i think i can help you

Comment: @ShowStopper - Here's a link to the jsFiddle that I have created in my public dashboard.  Mind you, I have had to modify the code to take out WordPress/Cherry Framework dependencies.  Otherwise, it seems to be behaving exactly like I described.  Let me know whether either of you are able to make heads or tails of it.  Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/vasilios/057v26zv/4/

Comment: better is to create an image rather than css

Comment: @ShowStopper - Not possible then?

Comment: it will set with margin padding . which will affect responsive design . so better to use an image.

Comment: @ShowStopper - Even if I intend to use separate images for different media resolutions?  Mind you, I only want to display this header on a full screen resolution.  Note that I intend to have cut down versions of the logo displayed for different resolutions.  Either way, it seems like somebody has posted an answer which works, except that it relies on inline styling - something that shouldn't be too difficult to fix....

Answer (score 3):

Replace Your HTML Code

```
<div class="middleContent">
                <div class="clip_frame centervertical">
                    <div style="width:500px;" class="clip_frame header-left">
                        <span class="">
                            <img width="500" height="6px" alt="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuJmJ.gif">
                        </span>

                        <img width="500" height="80" alt="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KDly.gif">

                        <span style="top:-9px;position:relative;" class="">
                            <img width="500" height="6px" alt="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuJmJ.gif">
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div style=" height: 233px; margin-left: -14px; margin-right: -14px;  position: relative;  width: 220px;" class="clip_frame centervertical">
                    <span style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 1px;" class="">
                        <img width="217" height="70" alt="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kujPV.gif">
                    </span>

                    <span style="position: relative; top: 27px;" data-motopress-static-file="static/static-logo.php" data-motopress-type="static" class="clip_frame">
                        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOmBd.gif">
                    </span>

                    <span style="bottom: 1px; position: absolute; left: 1px;" class="">
                        <img width="217" height="70" alt="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpZ1l.gif">
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div style="width:500px;" class="clip_frame centervertical">
                    <div class="clip_frame header-right">
                        <span class="">
                            <img width="500" height="6px" alt="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuJmJ.gif">
                        </span>

                        <img width="500" height="80" alt="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KDly.gif">

                        <span style="top:-9px; position:relative;" class="">
                            <img width="500" height="6px" alt="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuJmJ.gif">
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Seems to solve my problem, except that it relies on inline styling to achieve the result.  Will look to transfer the inline styling to an external style sheet.  Once again, thank you for your help!

Comment: P.S. It would be good if you could include the whole solution/code snippet in the solution, so as to make it easier for the next person experiencing a similar problem.  Here's a link to my latest fiddle which may or may not help: http://jsfiddle.net/vasilios/057v26zv/6/